# How to make a sound bug on Focal Fossa to be fixed

Tags: sound, 20.04, alsa

During the Focal Fossa testing week I found a bug related to internal sound not working on Bay Trail, sound card chtmax98090, I reported it(#1871306).

My communication exchange happened to be only with automated procedures, I provided all the details and reports requested.

After that no communication at all, the status of the bug remains unchanged.

Recently, because of an improvement in alsa-project, I tested a fix for the bug and I added a comment to the bug report to explain it.

What I am expected to do to make the fix evaluated and used to fix the bug?

I noted that on the same architecture/sound card similar bugs have been ignored and they are still open.

Comment: Have you tested the issue occurs in *groovy*, it's more likely to be fixed in later releases unless it's a security flaw, or impacting a lot of users. You're the only person impacted by that bug, so it's unlikely to justify a SRU (*stable release update*) to fix for already *stable* releases such as 20.04/focal.

Comment: As i wrote, I filed the bug before Focal release. And, sorry, I'm not the only one, but just one in the few that filed the issue: the same issue has been filed over time a number of times against different releases.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about bugs being *ignored*. It's about limited number of volunteers triaging those bugs.

Fundamentally, what the Kernel developers need to know is:

- The priority of the bug. Issues that crash systems and lose data come first.
- Which project should be responsible for fixing the bug. If the next release of Alsa has already fixed the bug, Ubuntu won't waste effort re-fixing it.
- Where in the kernel code the bug is likely to be located.

To get to that point, bugs must be *triaged*. When a Kernel Team bug triager looks at the bug report, there are still a lot of questions. The more of these you can answer in the bug report, the more likely the bug will be triaged quickly. If the triager has to do all this research themself, the bug will wait until they feel like doing it (remember: volunteer). If the triager cannot reproduce the problem or lacks the correct hardware, the bug will wait until somebody else comes along.

- Does this bug affect lots of people? Does it crash systems or lose data? Or is it merely annoying?
- Has the bug been reported upstream (debian, alsa, kernel)? Have they made progress upon it?
- Is this new hardware that has never worked? Or did it work in the past (regression)? Can it be duplicated on similar hardware (reproducible)? If a regression, has it been bisected?
- Is the proposed fix a mere workaround? Or a real fix? Is the bug really a code problem? Or is it a design problem?

Now let's apply this to the Ubuntu-specific kernel development workflow:

Kernel developers are generally focused on the *next* release of Ubuntu (20.10). They can *backport* some features to older kernels...but that's generally unnecessary since most LTS users should be using HWE to get newer kernels.

- This means that you should always test the bug in the pre-release version of Ubuntu. If it's not fixed, then it's a valid bug report against the pre-release version of Ubuntu (and more likely to get triaged sooner).
- If it is broken in an older kernel, but fixed in a newer kernel, then somebody has already fixed the bug. It's a *[stable release update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) request* or a *backport request*. Developers might reject low-priority requests, since that newer (fixed) kernel will show up in the LTS with the next point release anyway.
- Release cycle deadlines: Ubuntu [20.10 Kernel Freeze](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-schedule/15531) will be in a couple weeks. If it's not fixed by then, you must re-test the bug with 21.04 in November as the Kernel Team moves on to the next pre-release version of Ubuntu.

If you are interested in becoming a [volunteer bug triager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BugSquad), we always welcome new participants!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for your long explanation. Unfortunately it is not answering my question: it's alsa and not an obscure component of the system. The fix is simply bringing in an alsa project GitHub repository as it is, or in other words to update it in Ubuntu. It is not requiring any special effort, the openSUSE devteam did it and contributed to the alsa projectI, I did it yet as a tester with them . I'm going to check 20.10 as you suggest.

Comment: Btw in my opinion it does make no sense to check 20.10: it will last few months by far less than 20.04. Furthermore, yes I'm the only one that filed that bug but out there is plenty of Chromebooks same architecture out of ChromeOS support, all potential Linux machines. If you think that I'm the only one concerned, it's non sense to go ahead: I worked the bug around  on my machine, therefore issue fixed, next problem.

Comment: In my comment I was  neither teaching which is the best workflow nor criticizing anyone, sorry if it sounded arrogant. Ok let's say that I test 20.10 before the release/freeze/whatever and I find the same bug and the same fix works: what's the next step? To file again the bug against 20.10 to provide all the reports? It will be again myself the only one affected, score 6. The testing is done and the fix has been accepted upstream by alsa-project: Arch is using it, openSUSE Tumbleweed is using it, I guess it is in some stage in Debian (unstable or testing).

Comment: it's a set of config files affecting nothing else than the specific sound card I use. Who is the person or the team I need to get in touch with to explain the story after I have filed the bug against 20.10? Can you provide me a link or some directions about where to find the team that maintains alsa or the kernel and how can I get in touch with them? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just did a quick search:
1. the package that should brings the missing configuration is alsa-ucm-conf
2. alsa-ucm-conf in groovy is version 1.2.2, the same as focal and it is missing the pieces of configuration that are fixing the issue
3. alsa-ucm-conf in Debian Sid is version 1.2.3, which is brignign the configuration files that are fixing the issue

What do you suggest me to do now?

Thank you.

Comment: Wow, that's great! 1. Update the bug header (different package) and edit the description (or add a comment).  2. Jump into IRC #ubuntu-bugs and request triage and help with 3 and 4 below. Be patient - the chatroom's busy hours depend upon where folks live.  3. Your September goal should be merging the 1.2.3 package into Ubuntu 20.10 before Debian Import Freeze.  4. Your November goal should be an SRU to backport the package (or just the files) the 20.04.

Comment: Additional tip: If you browse the Launchpad pages for the [alsa-ucm-conf package,](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-ucm-conf), you should see your bug in there. But you will also see the folks who touch that package often, and do code commits. Subscribe them to the bug, and reach out to them. Some might be dead-ends, but some might be able to help.

Comment: That's the kind of guidance  I was looking for! Thank you, let's see if I can make it.

Comment: It worked: now the bug has priority "high" and it is assigned.